# Is there anyway to create and use static html template in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio, templates, web, static, master-pages

I want to develop a static skin-only version of my website (ASP.NET MVC) before starting to code. 
I have about 20 static html page, they use a common master-page style (header, left-menu and footer). I want to make all the page look the same about the common parts, but I don't want to copy the template 20 times or more. I want to use someway like master-page.

I don't want to use master page or deploy to IIS, because when "debug" it's take to much time to load. Just "open-with-browser". I don't know is there anyway to reuse my html template (master-page) in VS. Dreamweaver have this function but I dont like it.

Comment: Do you mean just a plane hyper-text markup document? If so you can just create a new file: File -> New -> File -> HTML Page. This will open a plane html5 style document that you can save wherever and open in chrome(or whatever browser you fancy)and shift+f5 after you change the code. There is also a view in browser option under the file tab as well.

Comment: @CalebB: No, I want a MASTER-PAGE way for multiple pages! Thank :)